# Batch- file to move all files from one location to another in windows?

Tags: windows, batch, script

what I'm after is a batch file that will move all files from one folder to another, with the view eto schedule this as a task to run twice daily.

I know the whole move command etc but appears to be one file at a time or the folder it's self

i need the folder to remain there but the files inside to move

Cheers
Kyle

Comment: `move "full path to source folder\*.*"  "full path to target folder\"` Read http://ss64.com/nt/move.html

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5588264/batch-command-to-move-files-to-a-new-directory

Comment: why not move, then `mkdir`? is it a large folder tree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next script could help:

```
@ECHO OFF >NUL
SETLOCAL enableextensions
set "folderIn=D:\test\Files In"
set "folderOu=D:\test\Files Out"
set "logFile=%folderOu%\movelog.txt"
set "logToDo=>> "%logFile%" 2>&1"
rem above line causes that moved file names will be logged to file %logFile%
rem unrem next line if you need no log 
rem set "logToDo="
set /A "filesInNo=0"
for /f "tokens=*" %%# in ('dir /B "%folderIn%\*.*" 2^>NUL') do set /A "filesInNo+=1"
(
  echo === %date% %time% === %filesInNo%
  if %filesInNo% GTR 0 (
      move /Y "%folderIn%\*.*" "%folderOu%\"
  ) else (
      rem Nothing to copy
  )
)%logToDo%
rem next line for debugging purposes only
if not "%*"=="" type "%logFile%"
ENDLOCAL
goto :eof
```

For explanation see `rem` comments and **Resources** (required reading):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (additional particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`%~#` etc. special page) [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)
- (`>>`, `2>&1` etc. special page) [Redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)